# Query matching stock trading buyers/sellers based on conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that matches buyers and sellers for a fake stock market program. I eventually I'd like to use this to populate a transaction table to finalize peoples orders. This would also be in a SQL Server Agent Job. Here's the table I have:

```
Id    UserId    Type    QtyRemaining    Price   CreatedOn
1      3        BUY     50              1.00    2012-09-09 05:25:48.4470000
2      6        BUY     50              1.00    2012-09-09 19:25:34.4300000
3      5        SELL    30              1.00    2012-09-09 19:22:59.5900000
4      3        SELL    50              0.90    2012-09-09 06:39:34.9100000
5      2        SELLALL 50              1.00    2012-09-09 04:10:01.8400000
```

There are several conditions that need to be satisfied to make these matches:

1. A buyer must look for a seller that has >= amount of shares that the buyer wants if its a 'SELL' order. If its a 'SELLALL' order then the Qty must be equal for the buyer to buy the stock. E.g. The seller must be selling 50 shares and the buyer MUST be buying 50 shares at the same price or lower.
2. A buyer wants the minimum price for the stock.
3. If there are multiple sellers with the conditions above a buyer takes the oldest selling stock first after the minimum price.

So the pairs of traders would be #1 and #4, #2 and #5. Therefore #3 would still be pending.

Here's the code I was playing around with but I can't get it to match up properly with the minimum price and the oldest first:

```
select o.*, oa.*, r.* from [Order] o
join OrderActivity oa on o.Id = oa.OrderId
join (
    select o2.Id, o2.VideoId, o2.UserId, oa2.Price, oa2.QtyRemaining, o2.[Type] from [Order] o2
    join OrderActivity oa2 on o2.Id = oa2.OrderId
    where o2.Type = 'buy' and oa2.Status = 'open'
) as r on (o.VideoId = r.VideoId and oa.Price <= r.Price and r.QtyRemaining = oa.QtyRemaining and o.UserId != r.UserId)
where (o.Type = 'sell' or o.Type = 'sellall') and oa.Status = 'open'
```

Comment: Your conditions suggest that the same sell order could be used for more than one buy order.  In order words, your description would match id 4 with both 1 and 2.  Can you revise the conditions to match the results that you want?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Yes this is right because 2 users may submit the same order but #1 is granted first because its the oldest. Maybe I'm not understanding what your saying properly but I thought I outlined that in condition #3? Also thats how an actual market works if there is a seller which has the lowest price and 2 buyers want the same thing its first come first serve

Comment: I don't think this matching can be done in one query, since any potential matching depends on remaining items, not the whole set. You need to loop through all buyers and find a matching seller for each, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are welcome to play with this:

```
declare @Transactions as Table
  ( Id Int, UserId Int, Type VarChar(8), QtyRemaining Int, Price Money, CreatedOn DateTime )
insert into @Transactions ( Id, UserId, Type, QtyRemaining, Price, CreatedOn ) values
  ( 1, 3, 'BUY',     50, 1.00, '2012-09-09 05:25:48.447' ),
  ( 2, 6, 'BUY',     50, 1.00, '2012-09-09 19:25:34.430' ),
  ( 3, 5, 'SELL',    30, 1.00, '2012-09-09 19:22:59.590' ),
  ( 4, 3, 'SELL',    50, 0.90, '2012-09-09 06:39:34.910' ),
  ( 5, 2, 'SELLALL', 50, 1.00, '2012-09-09 04:10:01.840' )

-- Split the transactions into temporary working tables.
declare @Buyers as Table
  ( Id Int, UserId Int, Type VarChar(8), QtyRemaining Int, Price Money, CreatedOn DateTime )
declare @Sellers as Table
  ( Id Int, UserId Int, Type VarChar(8), QtyRemaining Int, Price Money, CreatedOn DateTime )
insert into @Buyers
  select Id, UserId, Type, QtyRemaining, Price, CreatedOn
    from @Transactions
    where Type = 'BUY'
insert into @Sellers
  select Id, UserId, Type, QtyRemaining, Price, CreatedOn
    from @Transactions
    where Type like 'SELL%'

-- Process the buy orders in the order in which they were created.
declare @BuyerId as Int = ( select top 1 Id from @Buyers order by CreatedOn )
declare @SellerId as Int
declare @Balance as Int

while @BuyerId is not NULL
  begin
  -- Pair a seller, if possible, with the current buyer.
  ; with Willard as (
  select Row_Number() over ( order by S.Price, S.CreatedOn ) as Priority,
    S.Id as S_Id, S.QtyRemaining as S_QtyRemaining,
    B.QtyRemaining as B_QtyRemaining
    from @Sellers as S inner join
      @Buyers as B on B.Id = @BuyerId and
        case 
          when S.Type = 'SELL' and B.QtyRemaining <= S.QtyRemaining then 1
          when S.Type = 'SELLALL' and B.QtyRemaining = S.QtyRemaining then 1
          else 0
          end = 1
    ) 
  select @SellerId = S_Id, @Balance = S_QtyRemaining - B_QtyRemaining
    from Willard
    where Priority = 1
  -- Display the result.
  select @BuyerId as BuyerId, @SellerId as SellerId, @Balance as RemainingShares
  -- Update the working tables.
  if @Balance = 0
    delete from @Sellers
      where Id = @SellerId
  else
    update @Sellers
      set QtyRemaining = @Balance
      where Id = @SellerId
  delete from @Buyers
    where Id = @BuyerId
  -- Find the next buy order.
  set @BuyerId = ( select top 1 Id from @Buyers order by CreatedOn )
  end

-- Display any unfilled orders.
select 'Unmatched Buy', *
  from @Buyers
select 'Unmatched Sell', *
  from @Sellers
```

Comment: Damn! I will take a look, lots too look at!

Answer (score 2):

try this

Briefly ,

1.Rank buyer based on the createddate(named as stocks in the below query) 
2.Rank seller based on    the price,createddate(named as lowNoldstock)
3.Get the **matching rank**

```
select stocks.*,lowNoldStock.* 
from    (select *,row_number() over(order by createdon) as buyerrank
         from stocktable(nolock)  where c='buy' ) stocks 
inner join 
       (select  *,row_number() over(order by price,createdon) as sellerrank
        from stocktable(nolock) where [type]='sell' or [type]='sellall' ) lowNoldstock
on      (stocks.qty<=lowNoldStock.qty and lowNoldStock.type='sell') 
       or (lowNoldStock.type='sellall' and stocks.qty=lowNoldStock.qty and stocks.price>=lowNoldStock.price)
where  lowNoldStock.sellerrank=stocks.buyerrank
```

[test script in sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ece20/7/0) ,for some reason it is showing partial result in sql fiddle
This works in my local database